# How to Open .one file in android ? Microsoft Onenote

Tags: android, onenote

Please, I need to know the way to open .one file in android environment

Note that I install OneNote from play store and i didn't found the option to [Open, Add] any OneNote file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I think You can't open .one files directly. You need to share your notebook on SkyDrive from OneNote on PC, using File > Share. Then the notebook will be available in the mobile OneNote app.

For more details refer this : [https://support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sync-notes-between-an-Android-phone-and-a-computer-0288aab7-9a46-4b86-b324-0c151c8f684f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

you can Try with this app : [mobile noter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.themsteam.mobilenoter)